# Image (Error) User memory limit exceeded

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, landsat, sentinel-2, band

I was trying download spectral bands. Below show my scrip, the first part do a mask for take off land cover i don't wish. After, i do a date cube, for download the spectral band, where each band is a temporal image.
I'm getting this error:

> Image (Error) User memory limit exceeded

```
///////////////////////////
  // FUNCION PARA ENMASCARAR
  
  var masking = function(img) { 
    
  
                            
      var coberturas = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
                        .select('discrete_classification');
                        
       var clases = ee.List([20,30,40,111,112,113,114,
                            115,116,121,122,123,124,125,126]);
                        
    var mascara = coberturas
                    .updateMask(coberturas.eq(ee.Image.constant(clases))
                    .reduce(ee.Reducer.anyNonZero()));
                    
   var rojo_mask = img.select('SR_B4').updateMask(mascara).rename('Rojo_Mask')

   return img.addBands(rojo_mask)  }

///////////////////////////

var rojo = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
                    .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2020-12-31')
                    .map(masking)
                    .select('Rojo_Mask');
                    
                    
                   
                    
                    

// Función para stackear para la coleccion en una sola imagen

var stackCollection = function(collection) {
  var first = ee.Image(collection.first()).select([]);
  var appendBands = function(image, previous) //appends agrega una banda a una imagen
  {return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);};
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBands, first));};
  
  

// Función para generar mascaras para cada scene.

var getSceneMask = function(scene) {
  var dateString = ee.Date(scene.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
  var mask = scene.select('Rojo_Mask').gt(-9999).updateMask(ee.Image(1));
  return mask.rename(dateString);};

// Mascara stackeada para la colección

var MaskCol = stackCollection(rojo.map(getSceneMask));

// Generar una lista de fechas para la colección 

var datelist = ee.List(MaskCol.bandNames()).map(function(date){return ee.Date(date).format('yyyy-MM-dd')});


// Stackear bandas y renombrarlas por fecha

var rojo_stacked = stackCollection(rojo.select('Rojo_Mask')).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);

Map.addLayer(rojo_stacked)
print(rojo_stacked)

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: rojo_stacked,
  description: 'Rojo',
  folder : 'Tesis',
  region: geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:32719',
  scale: 100})
```

Answer (score 1):

The collection `rojo` has 619,557 images in it, which means when you attempt to stack them with `iterate`, you're attempting to create an image with 619,577 bands, the lists are 600k elements long, etc.

You probably meant to do a `filterBounds` on some region (not included in your code), to reduce the size of that collection.